# how to use cache while working with a heavy excel file for extracting data using python

Tags: python, excel, caching

HI I have a rather huge excel file (.xlsx) and has got multiple tab that I need to access for various purpose. Every time I have to read from excel it slows the process down. is that any way I can load selected tabs to cache the first time I read the excel book?  thanks

Comment: Personally I'd read each tab into a separate pandas dataframe and access those as required.

Comment: What library are you using to read the Excel file?

Comment: using pandas, this would be an example  - filename = self.live; Lfile = pd.ExcelFile(filename);df = pd.read_excel(Lfile, self.tabname)